# jquery mobile popup position and close button behavior in mobile safari

Tags: ios, google-apps-script, mobile-safari, jquery-mobile-popup

I developed an app using the jquery mobile library and styling in google apps script. Unfortunately the jquery mobile popups that I am utilizing in the app exhibit odd position behavior and the popup close buttons also exhibit unexpected behavior. 
The popups use the position to window either by default or designating this in the popup href button. The result is the popup always positions center relative to the entire page instead of the window.
The popup close buttons may or may not actually close the popup and for some reason invokes a window scroll down.

From what research I have done the popup position issue may be related to the iframe sandboxing that google apps script does, however this did not appear to occur prior to the iframe changes that google did to apps script, although this particular app always used iframe sandboxing before and never seemed to have a problem in iOs devices.

I have searched for the problem in regards to the popup close button behavior but have not found anything.

The app was tested on iPhone 7 iOs 10.0.3 safari browser/chrome browser/firefox browser, iPhone 4S iOs 9.3.4 safari browser, iPad Air iOs 10.0.2 safari browser, all rendering the same results. This behavior is not present in any of the current desktop browsers or in chrome browser on a Nexus 5.

The question, is there a possible workaround to fix this observed behavior or is anyone aware if this is a google apps script problem or a mobile safari problem and if a solution is being worked on?

Here is a link to a test app that was created specifically to test this problem.
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzxpdtCR7s-ej_YHmrlxV0ata9F-kyEnxif7kN2SKP3Xib3EaI/exec